# Rain drops falling into a cup via a Poisson process and leaving by exponential decay

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Imagine I place a cup out in the rain, and that point-like rain drops arrive in the cup via a Poisson process with rate parameter $\lambda_1$ (the time for a single cloud particle to release a drop of rain, amidst the population of particles composing the cloud, is exponentially distributed).  We cut a small hole at the bottom of the cup s.t. a rain drop will exist in the cup for an exponentially distributed period of time governed by a decay rate parameter $\lambda_2$.

Provided some integration period $T$, what is the expectation for the number of times where $\geq N$ rain drops will coexist in the cup?  What is the expected duration between events where $\geq N$ rain drops coexist in the cup?

Answer (score 0):

You might look up [M/M/1 queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue).